# Is there a pictograms repository under an open-commercial license?

Tags: communication

I'm looking for pictograms repositories for non-verbal people. I found two types:

- ones that I need to pay like [PECS](http://www.pecsusa.com/pecssamples.php) or SPC,
- and others that are free but they have a no-commercial license like [arasaac](http://www.catedu.es/arasaac/index.php) or PiktoPlus.

My question is: Is there a pictograms repository under an open license and that I could use its pictograms with commercial purposes?

Comment: I would like to use the tags **pictogram**, **non-verbal** and **open-license** but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: No such tags, and not necessarily wise to introduce them unless other questions exist that could use them. If you find any though, link 'em here and I'll make the tag(s), which you can then tack onto those other questions as suggested edits for a little rep bump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one! http://straight-street.org/

Those pictos have a [Creative Commons BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/) license.